# Cannot get Private Key of USB Token from IIS

Tags: c#, api, iis, usb, token

I am developing an asp.net c# web-application to sign PDF files on the server side. I am using a USB Token to sign the PDF file. When i developed on the development box, I can able to sign the document. But when the same code is hosted on IIS , I cannot able to sign the document. I am not getting any exception too. The error provided is **An Internal error occurred**.

I got stuck on this stage. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

Its look like permission related issue, you could try to use the different application pool account like network service or custom account which user has full access control permission or try to give IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions to the USB. 
you can capture some data using [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

to set application pool identity in iis please follow the below steps:

1)open iis manager.

2)select the application pool and click on the advanced setting from the action pane.

3)click on the identity.

4)in application pool identity windows click the custom account radio button and set username and password or select built-in account like network service from the drop-down.

[image]

[image]

to set application pool permission use `IIS AppPool\apppool name`.

Comment: Hi #Janvi. I tried, but still get the same error. It seems that USB Token has blocked access from iis. I can get anything besides Private key.

Comment: Could you please share the iis application pool identity and assign USB permission snapshot? did you try to use process monitor?

Comment: To access USB Token from web browser, you may like to use Signer.Digital browser extension, documented in detail in SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885